# Merging/show multiple data in a single row pivot data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a hard time working in this SQL pivot. I noticed that using pivot will only show 1 data.

This is my sample table.

| day | time | act |
| --- | --- | --- |
| monday | 10:00am | watch tv |
| monday | 11:00am | play online |
| tuesday | 8:00am | breakfast |
| tuesday | 12:00 | lunch |

result should be:

| playtime | monday | tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| schedule | 10:00am - watch TV 11:00am - play online | 10:00am - breakfast 11:00am - lunch |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What were the sql commands that you tried? It could be useful if you added them to your question. Also, where does the field "playtime" comes from? You may want to specify that too.

Comment: the schedule comes from another table. i just used the normal pivot command. was not in my unit so i cant add them. sorry

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: sorry about that, was using sql2012

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic pivot query to do this. try below query

```
declare @columns varchar(max)='',@sql nvarchar(max);

Create table #temp (Name nvarchar(max));

insert into #temp select distinct [Day] from YourTableName --inert distinct column for pivot query

SELECT @columns+=QUOTENAME(Name) + ',' from #temp
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

select [Day], (Act+'-'+Times) Act into #temppivot  from testpivot-- concat act and time column

SELECT distinct [day],STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Act FROM #temppivot tt where tt. [Day]=t.[Day] FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') ACT into #temppivotFinal from #temppivot t  -- merge same day act as comma separated

set @sql='SELECT * FROM
(select ''Schedule'' Playtime,* from #temppivotFinal) t

PIVOT(max([Act])
FOR [Day] IN ('+@columns+')
) AS pivot_table'

EXEC (@sql)

drop table #temp
drop table #temppivot
drop table #temppivotFinal
```

Comment: How do you know theck is using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: thank you for this, will try it when i get back in my unit. i hope this will be what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 'schedule',
       string_agg(case when date = 'Monday'
                       then concat(time, ' - ' act),
                  '
') within group (order by time) as Monday,
       string_agg(case when date = 'Tuesday'
                       then concat(time, ' - ' act),
                  '
') within group (order by time) as Tuesday
from t;
```